# Developer version of amazon MWS API

Tags: amazon-mws

I want to have a look on amazon MWS api but it needs a special type of account (seller account) that I do not have one. I want just to see and use the technical aspects of the API with mock data.

So does amazon provide a "developer" version of their amazon MWS API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have an Amazon seller account to use it.  There are no sandboxes or developer versions to play with.  You can download a client library where they have mock data for you to look at.  That's right here: https://developer.amazonservices.com/

But that's the best you can get without being a seller.